# Link Dont work in first page Hero image

Tags: links, buttons

i try to add a link to hero image button (see in screen shot) but the link is not responce in any way.

2) If i move the mouse from hero image to menu there is a "light" effect or somthing that change the appear .. please se the video below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EDfdKV7ImpNBRwOXgjRQ9ZH2KIKIyReG/view

[Here is the site](http://shorturl.at/xzF36)

[image]

Comment: Here is the link https://cutt.ly/ztyVaS2

Comment: If you inspect the button you will see it has href="#", that # should be a URL.  There should be some option to pick or add a URL inside the admin where ever you setup this slide.

Comment: Well, thank you for you answer mate. I just add a link inside there. But still remain the same. Please look in screenshot.http://imgbox.com/GGk91TIO

Is like some frame cover all this area, but i can't find were it is..